# localStorage does not seem to work in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, local-storage, angular2-services

I have a simple service that gets and sets item in a local NOTES object array by using localStorage, but everytime the pages refreshes the data entered before is lost, and only the initial data in the const NOTES array remains. I don't know what I am doing wrong here.

Service code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { NOTES } from './localnotes';
import { INote } from './shared/interfaces';

const STORAGE_KEY = 'notes';

@Injectable({
 providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NotesService {


   constructor() { 
   localStorage.setItem(STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(NOTES));
  }

  getNotes() {
   try {
     return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY));
   } catch (e) {
     console.error('Error getting data from localStorage', e);
     return null;
   }
 }

deleteNotes() {

 }

 newNote(note: INote) {
    const tempnote = note;
    NOTES.push(tempnote);
    localStorage.setItem(STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(NOTES));
 }

}
```

Component code:

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

import { INote } from '../shared/interfaces';
import { NotesService } from '../notes.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-notes',
  templateUrl: './notes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./notes.component.css']
})
export class NotesComponent implements OnInit {
  notes: INote[];
  newNote: boolean = false;
  hideNewNote: boolean = false;


  constructor(private noteService: NotesService) {
    const data = noteService.getNotes();
    this.notes = data;
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  makeNewNote() {
    this.newNote = true;
  }

  getValues(title, note, tag) {
      this.newNote = false;
      const tempnote = {title: title, note: note, date: new Date(), 
tag: tag};
      this.noteService.newNote(tempnote);
      this.notes = this.noteService.getNotes();
  }

}
```

const NOTES:

```
import { INote } from './shared/interfaces'; 

export const NOTES: INote[] = [
    {title: "title1", note: "note1", date: new Date(), tag: "tag1"}
];
```

Comment: You seem to be overwriting the localStorage `notes` in the constructor of the `NotesService` with what is in `NOTES`. You refresh the page, the application reinitializes the service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You overwrite the data on each refresh, you need to check if exists or not. Try like this:

```
constructor() {
  if(!this.getNotes()){
    localStorage.setItem(STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(NOTES));
  }
}
```

Comment: This answer makes more sense. Merging as I suggested has no effect as `NOTES` variable will already be empty at construction if the service is a singleton service. But since it is using the `localStorage`, it should be a singleton. So, this answer should be marked as accepted.

Comment: So if I am understanding this properly then the NOTES const array is actually not getting updated. But only the "localStorage version" of it, that's why setting it to the NOTES in constructor wipes the localStorage too?

Answer (score 0):

It is because you assign `NOTES` variable to local storage in constructor. In every page reload, it replaces the empty array with the local storage data.

You can do like:

```
constructor() { 
   let mergedValues = [...NOTES];
   const previousValues = localStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY);
   if(previousValues){
      mergedValues = [...JSON.parse(previousValues)];
   }

   localStorage.setItem(STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(mergedValues));
}
```